# How to make Windows 10 stop asking me to open OneDrive account?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, popups

I've never had a OneDrive account, and I don't plan to. I haven't associated it with Windows 10 Home, which I installed for free on my laptop promptly when it came out. But in the last week, I've been seeing a window pop up in the center of my screen at least once a day, asking me if I want to create a OneDrive account. There's nothing to click that says "I'm not interested in OneDrive". I googled around and found some things about removing OneDrive, but they all seem to start from the situation of already having a OneDrive account.

I'm aware that on Windows 10 Professional you can use the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) to turn OneDrive off, but that doesn't help with Windows 10 Home.
I've also seen other solutions, but they involve clicking tabs and buttons that I don't see when I open the OneDrive Settings:
[screen shot of OneDrive Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCfDo.jpg).

Is there a way to control in Windows 10 Home what I can see in the Settings for OneDrive? Or some other way to turn it off?

Comment: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in my question & answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: Thanks, @DavidPostill I downloaded and installed that, but when I tried running it as the instructions are in the question this has been marked duplicate of, I got [this message](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18919457/2017-03-10%2015_37_34-Microsoft%20Management%20Console.jpg).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Windows 10 to try and fix that.